# Generate xml in bpel file from diagram

Tags: bpel

How can generate xml code in BPEL file (.bpel) from diagram. I think every control have different attribute. Does anyone know attribute for every control in BPEL?
Plz help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

WS-BPEL is an XML-based language and is an OASIS standard. The standard itself only describes the XML represenation and does not give any recommendations on how BPEL elements can be visualized. The specification lists all elements and attributes of the language in detail [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/OS/wsbpel-v2.0-OS.pdf).